# Fazer autenticação automaticamente utilizando JCIFS em JAVA

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

Estou construindo uma solução em Java onde o objetivo é de ser capaz de fazer com que os usuários que estão logados em um domínio do Windows possam autenticar automaticamente com suas credenciais do Windows ao iniciar uma aplicação web. Para tal estou utilizando a biblioteca JCIFS. Porém quando faço o `deploy` da aplicação, ao executar o comando `remote.getRemoteUser();` ele me retorna nada e não o nome do usuário que esta acessando a pagina.

Segue meu `web.xml` e estou utilizando a `lib` **JCIFS-1.2.17.jar**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver o problema relatado?

Comment: Você podia postar o seu código em texto formatado ao invés de imagens? Além disso, o que você quer dizer por "ele me retorna nada"? Você quer dizer que ele retorna `null`?

Comment: Retorna uma string vazia ! Acredito eu que, quando chamo a pagina ele mostra um dialogo solicitando login e senha, eu so consigo abrir a pagina que chamei quando passo login e senha vazio, sera que é isso ?